# iPhone bring up popup on UITableViewCell click

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I have a static UITableView and I want one of my cells to pop up a dialog box when it is clicked.

I have the code for a popup, and I am using the following method to do things on cell select

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

How can I determine that it's the cell that I want, e.g. test the cell identifier? I'm worried about going by position in case I add a new item to my table, although I know I can do this

```
int row=indexPath.row;
int section=indexPath.section;
```

I'm using storyboarding with IOS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have is table with multiple sections, I suggest defining your own method for counting

```
- (int)getGlobalRowFor:(int)row at:(int)section {
if(section == 0) {
    return row;
} else {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < section; i++) {
        count += [[[self.sections objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sectionCount"] intValue];
    }
    return count + row;
   }
}
```

Which tells you where it is in the globel aspect. Other than that you just need to ask you view where it is positioned on screen and you should be good to go!

Comment: That looks like it will work, but how do I assign the sections to a variable as in your bit about self.sections (I think I'm missing something stupid)

Comment: `self.sections` is my instance variable keeping number of elements in each section. It is up to you how you keep the number of it, I create the sections myself based on analysis algorithm performed when I receive data.

Answer (score 0):

You need find the unique property of that cell, for example, the position, the text, or the image etc.
If no unique property, u can set the tag property a unique value when create it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer by Michal would work with a little extra work on my part.

I actually changed the app so that the cell just loaded another tableview because I decided it was better to separate that functionality out.

Creating a push segue from a static table is easy with storyboarding, just right click the cell and drag to the desired view.